# AWSa APIGatewayV2HTTPRequest does not contain RequestContext

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to setup an API Gateway that forwards requests to a Lambda function. Precisely I struggle to setup CORS properly. When handling the request in my Lambda function the incoming event does not have the `RequestContext` information set. Hence I don't know when I handle an `OPTIONS` request.

My debug code: `in` is the `APIGatewayV2HTTPRequest`

```
log.Printf("type: %s", reflect.TypeOf(in))
log.Printf("req: %+v", in)
```

Output:

```
type: events.APIGatewayV2HTTPRequest 

...
RequestContext:{
  RouteKey: 
  AccountID:xxx
  Stage:default
  RequestID:dB7h2jEcFiAEMkA=
  Authorizer:<nil>
  APIID:xxx
  DomainName:xxx
  DomainPrefix:xxx
  Time: 
  TimeEpoch:0 
  HTTP:
    {Method: Path: Protocol: SourceIP: UserAgent:}
```

It seems `RequestContext.HTTP` is not set and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the api gateway payload version to v2. For some reason it was set to v1 and therefor the event was not properly populated.